# Simple programming for loop

Tags: language-agnostic, for-loop

Let suppose I create a class, and in this class I declare a method that will run a loop.
My question is what will be behavior of loop, if I dispose the object of class and condition of loop is yet true - will loop execute or terminate.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with approach you've adopted, well you can check that disposed object in loop condition and exit the loop, but i'm really not sure about your requirement, please specify the programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the object (variable) is managed by a single thread. So you may not be able dispose of easily because the thread is still running in the loop. If you mult-thread and you call in a method that modifies this variable (your object) on the a different thread you may crash your program. If your loop in a UI thread which has a message pump (sta thread) and you call a method directly from another thread then you app will crash as this is not allowed.

All in all what do you want to do ? Mark Byers's condition "The code keeps running" is the most possiable outcome of this I think. But you have a bug either way - don't attempt to drive a car and then just jump out of it without stopping.